# Cross Product within a Singular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was doing a particular problem in multivariable calculus where I had to find a cross product within a singular matrix, non invertible matrix, to find a solution to a linear system:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0  \\
0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The solution said to treat the matrix multiplication as a series of dot products so that $<x, y, z>$ is orthogonal to the rows of $3X3$ matrix. And to do so, it asked to found the cross product of the first two rows of $3X3$ matrix: $<1,2,3>\times<4,5,6>$.
I wondered if other pairs of cross product would preserve the "orthogonal" property, and it did: $<1,2,3> \times <4,5,6> = <4,5,6>\times<7,8,9> = <1,2,3>\times<7,8,9>$...etc (assuming the scalar multiples are also equal).
I am curious why this only occurs in a singular matrix and if there is any intuitive reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the matrix is singular, one of the columns can be written as a linear combination of the other two columns, i.e. the vectors in the set
$$\left\{ \left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{c} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{c} 7 \\ 8 \\ 9 \end{array} \right) \right\}$$
are linearly dependent. This means that the span of the three vectors above is in fact a $2$-dimensional plane in $\mathbb R^3$.

Now recall that taking the cross product of two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ gives you a third vector that is orthogonal to both. So what's happening when you take cross products in all the cases you listed above is that you are finding a vector that is orthogonal to every vector in this plane (i.e. a normal vector to the plane). So it is no surprise that you get the same answer in each case.